# Elasticsearch Ram recommendation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm deploying an Elasticsearch cluster with roughly 40GB a day with a time-to-live of 365 days. Write speed would be around 50 msgs/sec. Reads would be mostly driven by user dashboards, so the read frequency won't be high. What would be the best hardware requirements for this amount of data? How many master and data nodes may require in this situation?

Comment: do you need replica and HA?

Comment: Don't need HA setup.

Answer (score 1):

obviously base on search index rate you should choose the hardware. 50 msg/sec is very low for elasticsearch. you have total 14.6TB data that is your 85 percent of total disk (base on 85% watermark). this means that you need 17TB disk. I think you can use one server with 128GB RAM and atleast 10 Core CPU and 17TB disk or have two server with half of this config. one server is master and data node and one server will be only data node.

Comment: I have another ES instance that would handle around 5000 writes/sec. Would I need ssd for that kind of message rate?

Comment: for 5000 m/s , you must test it. it depend on type and size of docs, analyzers and search rate. it is not all about writing on disk. you should consider how much processing you have on the messages. I think SSD would not resolve this sitution.  perhaps you need more than one server